# How to change template engine of node.js project?

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine

I have [this](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo) node.js project, it uses jade template. But I need to use simple html pages. Guideline needed for safe transformation.

I need to use complete .html pages like index.html, login.html. Without any template engine to show at routes like localhost:3000 and localhost:3000/login.html. Which should work with full functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change it in `config/express.js`:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
```

For example, if you want to use [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), then remove `"jade": "latest",` in `packages.json` and add `"handlebars": "latest"`. Then run `npm install` and edit `config/express.js`:

```
 app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
```

Comment: Can't we render full html pages on routes without any template engine?

Comment: @XIMRX You can send any html without using template engines, but you wont be able to customize it.

Answer (score 1):

Express server static html files by default.

Place your html files in **/public** folder:

```
    ...
    /public
       index.html
       login.html
       ...
```

and go localhost:3000/ or localhost:3000/login.html 
but this is static files and then the application logic should be on the front-end. For example using angular or backbone.

Comment: Yes best possibility so far, any way to manipulate logic using node?

Comment: What logic? Diffrent logic uses diffrent approach. if need logic on render page - use template engine (jade). if only post data to server (aka login page) simple post to your route then logic. Samples: Server API (node + express) + AngularJs App (front) get and post data and render templates OR classic - server render templates (jade) + browser render views and post data to server OR combine for diffrent parts your app. 

In general template engines need for logic ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/any_location', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('Location_to_htmlFile');
})
```

Comment: please make sure to always describe what you are trying to do ^^